# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, dplyr

When I am trying to run following function :

```
foo <- air_reserve %>%
  mutate(reserve_date = date(reserve_datetime),
         reserve_hour = hour(reserve_datetime),
         reserve_wday = wday(reserve_datetime, label = TRUE),
         visit_date = date(visit_datetime),
         visit_hour = hour(visit_datetime),
         visit_wday = wday(visit_datetime, label = TRUE),
         diff_hour = time_length(visit_datetime - reserve_datetime, unit = "hour"),
         diff_day = time_length(visit_datetime - reserve_datetime, unit = "day")
  )
```

I am getting following error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

How can I solve this issue ?

## Note:

`foo` function is taken from this [link](https://www.kaggle.io/svf/1834414/0e00324611a5d00958c6b418517570d0/__results__.html#)

Comment: Please include all packages you are using. Also share some reproducible example. The error suggests that you have non-numeric variables on which you are trying to do a calculation. Most likely `visit_datetime` and `reserve_datetime` are not numeric and thus can not be subtracted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oww !!

I have solve this issue through following code :

```
foo <- air_reserve %>%
  mutate(reserve_date = date(reserve_datetime),
         reserve_hour = hour(reserve_datetime),
         reserve_wday = wday(reserve_datetime, label = TRUE),
         visit_date = date(visit_datetime),
         visit_hour = hour(visit_datetime),
         visit_wday = wday(visit_datetime, label = TRUE), 
         diff_hour = time_length(as.numeric(visit_datetime) - as.numeric(reserve_datetime), unit = "hour"),
         diff_day = time_length(as.numeric(visit_datetime) - as.numeric(reserve_datetime), unit = "day")

  )
```

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: @Sotos. Thank U.